# AngularJS + ChosenJS update model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an angular directive for the ChosenJS plugin based on this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs

What I want to do is have the model update when a value is selected.

```
function Foo($scope) {
  $scope.legalEntitiesList = [
      { name: 'Foo' },
      { name: 'Bar' }      
  ];

  $scope.legalEntity = { name: 'Foo' };
}

myApp.directive('chosen', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (!ngModel) return;

    element.addClass('chzn-select');

    $(element).chosen()
            .change(function(e) {
                console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });

    scope.$watch(attrs.chosen, function() {
        $(element).trigger('liszt:updated');
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: linker
  }
}]);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/MQzXq/7/. If you select a different option, the model value is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the select to bind to `legalEntity.name` instead of just `legalEntity` your fiddle works.

```
<select id="legalEntityInput" chosen="legalEntitiesList" ng-model="legalEntity.name" ng-options="legalEntity.name for legalEntity in legalEntitiesList" data-placeholder="Select..."><option></option></select>
```

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQzXq/8/) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but I'm lacking reputation points.  However, please note that newer versions of Chosen use the event `chosen:updated` instead of `liszt:updated` -- Thanks for the video, Dustin!